# JavaFX8 change from predicate binding to KeyPress action instead

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a TableView with textboxes in each column. If I write something in one of the textboxes, the tableview gets filtered based on all the textboxes. For now the code I have listens to change in the textboxes, and filters as soon as the text changes.  The following code works fine, but is it any way to make it more  efficient?

Probably the best way would be to listen to a enter press instead of filtering on every change in the textfield? Does predicateProperty support this? If not, how can I change from predicateProperty/binding to onKey press instead?

```
filteredItems.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(()
            -> li -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < li.size(); i++) {
                    {
                        if (!li.get(i).toLowerCase().
                        contains(
                                listOfTxtFields.get(i).getText().toLowerCase()
                        )) {
                            return false;
                        }

                    }

                }
                return true;
            },
            listOfTxtFields.stream().map(TextField::textProperty)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .toArray(new StringProperty[listOfTxtFields.size()])));
```

Comment: Could perhaps eventfilter be the resolution ?

Comment: Loading the lambda is also pretty slow, but the reason for that is my ugly date checker.. Any suggestions for this as well ?

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to fix this by some experimenting. It's pretty efficient, but could be a tad faster when it becomes tons of rows, so if you have any suggestions to making it faster, I would love to hear them. This is what I did:

Created a method that will be called each time a user presses enter on a textField in the columns:

void filter() {

```
    DateTest dateTest = new DateTest();
    filteredItems.setPredicate(li -> {

        for (int i = 0; i < li.size(); i++) {
            if (dateTest.isValidDate(listOfTxtFields.get(i).getText().replace("a", "").replace("b", ""))) {

                try {
                    dateTest.isValidDate(li.get(i));
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Date date1 = sdf.parse(li.get(i));
                    Date date2 = sdf.parse(listOfTxtFields.get(i).getText().replace("a", "").replace("b", ""));
                    if (listOfTxtFields.get(i).getText().contains("a")) {
                        if (date1.after(date2)) {
                            return true;

                        }
                    }
                    if (listOfTxtFields.get(i).getText().contains("b")) {
                        if (!date1.before(date2)) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (!date1.equals(date2)) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Table.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            } else {
                if (!li.get(i).toLowerCase().
                        contains(
                                listOfTxtFields.get(i).getText().toLowerCase()
                        )) {

                    return false;

                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    });

}
```